# Firefox OS Contacts API saving contact as unnamed

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla

I'm having a problem with the Firefox OS Contacts API.

I'm just copying the code from this page https://wiki.mozilla.org/ContactsAPI#Create_contact_example

```
var contact = new mozContact({name: ["John Doe"], givenName: ["John"], familyName: ["Doe"]});

var request = navigator.mozContacts.save(contact);

request.onsuccess = function() {
   alert("Success saving contact. New contact ID: " + contact.id);
};

request.onerror = function() {
   alert("Error saving contact.");
};
```

But the contact is saved as "No name". I didn't change anything in the code (it's from the official documentation) and the permissions are ok, as readwrite. I'm running on the simulator. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Which version of the simulator do you use?

Comment: Where are you seeing the "No name" string? On the Contacts app, I assume. How are you testing this? Do you close the Contacts app after saving and before checking the saved contact? Where is your code running? A privileged app? Did you grant the permission using the simulator?

Comment: @paa I'm using 4.0 version (FxOS 1.1).

Comment: @ReubenMorais This string appears on the Contacts app after running my simple app with the code above. I already tried to close the contacts app or even restarting the simulator, but it always appears as "No name". It's running on the simulator as a privileged app with the right permissions (althought it isn't needed for the simulator).

Comment: This is strange, the placeholder No Name is used when both `givenName` and `familyName` are missing. Actually even then, organization, telephone and email are preferred, if existing.

Comment: The most strange is that I just copied the code from the documentation and tested it without any change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! The example code in that page matches the code on mozilla-central, or the latest version of Gecko/Firefox OS. Things are slightly different in 1.1, you have to initialize the mozContact object like this:

```
var contact = new mozContact();
contact.init({name: ["John Doe"], givenName: ["John"], familyName: ["Doe"]});
```

Sorry about that. Our Wiki is not the most friendly place to look for example code, since it's targeted at Firefox OS/Gecko hackers, not web developers. We try to keep MDN updated about compatibility issues like this; see the example code in the MDN Contacts page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Contacts

Comment: @ReubenMorals I have a FirefoxOS device and want to create an App which require Contacts permission. Need some help for the permissions. The same code on the link you gave is not working.